# Correct use of "hereby" on a formal letter

Tags: word-usage

Can I use hereby in this sentece below?

As requested, I hereby state that I do not have life insurance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In most contexts it is correct.

Comment: It's correct, but sounds a bit awkward, redundant, and overly formal. Maybe try: *As requested, I declare that I do not have life insurance.*

Answer (score 0):

According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hereby):

> #### hereby
>
> Adverb
>
> - by this means
>
> Examples of *hereby* in a Sentence:
>
> - I *hereby* declare the Olympic Games officially open.
> - The sum will *hereby* be charged to your account.
> - The parties to the lawsuit *hereby* agree to settle the matter out of
>   court.

The [graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20hereby%20state%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20hereby%20state%3B%2Cc0) shows that now this phrase is correct and appropriate, though it sounds rather formal.